# Generate PDF of data summaries at specified times within repeat loop in R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, dplyr, repeat

I use a repeat loop within R to perform data wrangling and analyses on continuously ingested data, which has been my way of carrying out automated and near real-time analyses on it. Within the repeat loop, the system sleeps for 60 seconds and then restarts. I want some code within this repeat loop function that will generate a PDF of a data summary as a specified time; let's say midnight.

I am just going to use the `mpg` data set here in R as a very basic example (cannot share my actually data set as it is **sensitive** data. What will happen here is a a scatter plot (the same one) will be generated every 60 seconds, only with the title changing to include the current system time, just to show that it is working:-

```
interval=60 # system sleep time of 60 seconds

library(ggplot2)
repeat{

  currenttime<-Sys.time()
  
p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))# adds on the current time


plot(p)
print(Sys.time())# a check to see if it is working



  Sys.sleep(interval)# system sleeps for 60 seconds then repeats 
}
```

What I want to do is add additional code into this that when the system time reaches after midnight of a new day, that a PDF will be generated containing a data summary; with my *real* data set, this will be a summary of the data from the previous day. But for all intents and purposes, let's stick to the `mpg` data set. Included is the code that gives you the output as a PDF.

*data summary and PDF*

```
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
datasummary<-mpg%>%
  group_by(manufacturer)%>%
  summarise(Count=n(), MeanDispl=mean(displ))

pdf("datasummary.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
grid.table(datasummary)
dev.off()
```

This works outside of the repeat loop.

Here is one solution that I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
interval=60 # system sleep time of 60 seconds

library(ggplot2)
repeat{

  currenttime<-Sys.time()
  
p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))# adds on the current time


plot(p)
print(Sys.time())# a check to see if it is working



  Sys.sleep(interval)# system sleeps for 60 seconds then repeats 


reporttime<-as.ITime(Sys.time())
    
    if(reporttime>as.Date("00:00:00") &  reporttime<as.Date("00:03:00")){
      
      datasummary<-mpg%>%
      group_by(manufacturer)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(), MeanDispl=mean(displ))

      pdf("datasummary.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
      grid.table(dailyreport)
      dev.off()
      
    }
}
```

I put it as between "00:00:00" and "00:03:00" to ensure I don't miss this window due to the `interval`. How can I trigger the data summary PDF based on the time that I specify?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your if condition is not evaluated properly. At least for me this `data.table::as.ITime(Sys.time()) > as.Date("00:00:00")` produces an error.

If you set up the if condition differently your code seems to work. Note, to make it more transparent, this is now writing out multiple files with a time-stamp in their name as long as the current time is in the given interval (in this case: starttime + 15s).

```
#libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

#set time interval around current time (+ 15s) to make it reproducible
a <- strftime(Sys.time(), format="%H:%M:%S")
z <- strftime(Sys.time() + 15, format="%H:%M:%S")

#system sleep time set to 5 seconds
interval <- 5 

repeat{
  
  currenttime<-Sys.time()
  
  p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
    geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))# adds on the current time
  plot(p)
  print(Sys.time())# a check to see if it is working
  
  Sys.sleep(interval)# system sleeps
  
  if(currenttime > as.POSIXct(a, format="%H:%M:%S")  & 
     currenttime < as.POSIXct(z, format="%H:%M:%S")){

    datasummary<-mpg%>%
      group_by(manufacturer)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(), MeanDispl=mean(displ))
    
    pdf(file = paste0("datasummary_", strftime(currenttime, format="%H-%M-%S"), ".pdf"), 
        height = 11, width = 8.5)
    grid.table(datasummary)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great and working well, thank you very much. I managed to specify the times within the ```if```` loop and it appear to work alright.